# Returned string value becomes garbage

Tags: c, string, char, return

Im trying to pass a character `array` value to a character `pointer`. then this value gets returned to a method that is calling it, but after it gets returned, the value becomes garbage. can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * getname(){
     char nam[10];
     char * name;
     gets(nam);
     name = nam;
     return name;
}
main(){
       printf("%s",getname());
       getch();
}
```

everything is fine, until the string gets returned

Comment: Stop returning the address of a local variable in a called function. What you're doing is undefined behavior. And use `fgets()` rather than `gets()`. That function is so bad its been outright eliminated as of C11, deprecated in C99.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: I wish it were easy to search for this issue, it's so common for beginners to run into.  Also, OP, you don't need the pointer variable.  Arrays decay into pointers to the first element when necessary, you could have just (still incorrectly) written: `return nam`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return char\[\]/string from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416759/return-char-string-from-a-function)

Comment: Let's also remember that `gets()` is one of those dangerous functions with no buffer overflow protection. You're better off using `fgets()` such as with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921.

Comment: Remember to [upvote or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) an answer you found helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope of `nam` is local to function getname(), you are returning `nam` address through `name`  pointer

```
const char * getname(){
     char nam[10];
     :
     name = nam;
     return name;
}
```

allocate memory for `nam;` dynamically. like:

```
nam = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

additionally there may be bufferoverun don't use `gets()`, do like:

```
nam = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
fgets( nam, 10, stdin );
```

You also not need to use `name` an extra variable simple `return nam` is good.

```
const char * getname(){
     char * nam = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
     fgets( nam, 10, stdin ); 
     return nam;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to write `sizeof(char)` as it's 1 by definition.

Comment: @JanHudec yes not necessary :)

Comment: Agreed. Extra `sizeof(char)` doesn't hurt, forgetting `sizeof(int)` sure would.

Comment: @JanHudec Yes that's why I believe it good practice to use `sizeof` Thanks!

Comment: Actually it clogs your code unnecessarily (IMO). And if you want to safeguard yourself from type changes, you should use something like: `char *nam = malloc (10 * sizeof(*nam));`. Still it's not my style to downvote "competing" answers, especially when the infraction is minor :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks  for the suggestion. yes! `char *nam = malloc (10 * sizeof(*nam));` is correct choice. Thanks. And we are not "competing"  we are together helping. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `nam` variable has function scope. This means that once the function ends, the memory for that variable is freed. So the pointer pointing to that memory that you return will not be valid any more.

You could pass in the pointer: (a bit pointless in this case, as you can see)

```
void getname(char *name)
{
  gets(name);
}
```

You could `malloc` (bad, because then you need to `free` it again at some point):

```
const char * getname(){
     char * name = malloc(10);
     gets(name);
     return name;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning also 'how this common problem is usually tackled' design-wise

Comment: Yes, in C you have to watch what was allocated and has to be freed where all the time. C++ can do most of that for you, but in C there is no escape from it.

Comment: You have small error in your code correct is as `gets(name);`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `return name` is returning the address of a stack variable, one that's gone out of scope after the function returns.

There are a couple of ways to fix this (at least).

The first is to have the address allocated *outside* of the function and then passed in:

```
char *getname (char *buff) {
    strcpy (buff, "pax");
    return buff;
}

char name[20];
printf ("Name is '%s'\n", getname (name));
```

The second is to use allocation functions that *don't* go out of scope on function exit (the pointers may but, as long as you pass them back, you can still get to the allocated memory):

```
char *getname (void) {
    char *buff = malloc (21);        // should really check this for failure.
    strcpy (buff, "pax");
    return buff;
}

buff = getname();
printf ("Name is '%s'\n", buff);
free (buff);                         // This is important, caller is responsible
                                     //   for freeing the memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `nam` static would do also:

```
const char * getname() {
  static char nam[10];
  ...
```

Beware: This code isn't thread-safe, as `nam` now is treated as if it were declared globally.