# find bugs in the c++ code below

Tags: c++

I have been asked to find bug in the following code
This code just prints abcdef, it seems pretty harmless to me but will appreciate any suggestions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char* append(const char* s1, const char* s2) {    
    string s(s1);    
    s += s2; 
    return s.c_str();
} 
void foo() { 
    const char* total = append("abc", "def"); 
    cout<<"total = "<<total<<endl;
}

int main() { 
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `s` ceases to exist when `append` returns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returned string value becomes garbage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020105/returned-string-value-becomes-garbage)

Comment: when s goes out of scope it will delete the pointer and hence will return from append function will consist of junk characters.

Comment: Thank you everyone, this cleared my confusion

Comment: The code lacks `#include <string>` so won't compile....

Comment: @TonyD I think it's implementation defined whether or not headers will include others, i.e. `<iostream>` and `<string>`.

Comment: @Tushar Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dangling pointer. `s` is destroyed when it goes out of scope, meaning the pointer to its internal data is no longer valid.