# Unable to return char pointer from function

Tags: c, pointers, return-value, ansi-c

Using `ansi c`
 
#define **STDC_VERSION** 201112L

I'm new to c, but took my lead from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416759/return-char-string-from-a-function)

Regardless of the approaches I've tried, I can't get the `sum` pointer to return.

Running the code succeeds (creates the correct number), and the `printf` in the `addNumericStrings` function works, but the `printf` in the `main` **does not** (prints nothing). I assume due to an error prior. I'm not getting any warnings on the build.

**output**

```
addNumericStrings.sum = 11234567889
```

**main**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "addViaStrings.h"

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "9999999999";
    char s2[] = "1234567890";

    char *sum = addNumericStrings(s1, s2);
    printf("main.sum = %s\n", sum);
}
```

**functions**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char addNumericStrings(char *s1, char *s2);
char leftPad(char *result, char *s, int maxlength);
int  findMaxLength(char *s1, char *s2);

char addNumericStrings(char *s1, char *s2){
    int maxlength = findMaxLength(s1, s2);
    char addend1[maxlength];
    char addend2[maxlength];

    char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 2) );

    int a1, a2, total;
    int carry = 0;

//  char sum[(maxlength + 2)]; // +1 in case addition rolls over past maxlength
    // Prepare the strings for manual addition
    leftPad(addend1, s1, maxlength);
    leftPad(addend2, s2, maxlength);
    // Buffer sum with ascii zeros (#48), not 0, and not "\0"
    for (int i = 0; i < (maxlength + 1); i++) { sum[i] = 48; }
    sum[maxlength + 1] = 0;
    // Run the manual addition
    // Start adding individual ints from end (right side)
    for (int i = maxlength - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        a1 = addend1[i] - '0'; // Convert to int
        a2 = addend2[i] - '0'; // Convert to int
        total = (a1 + a2 + carry);
        carry = 0;
        if ( total >= 10){
            carry += 1;
            total -= 10;
        }
        sum[i +1] = 48+total; // convert to ascii value for numbers (adding 48)
    }
    sum[0] = 48+carry; // add last carry to start of num always, even if 0
    sum[maxlength + 1] = '\0';
    printf("addNumericStrings.sum = %s\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

char leftPad(char *result, char *s, int maxlength){
    // Pads number to [000123456789]    
    ( ...snip... )
}

int findMaxLength(char *s1, char *s2){
// Returns int value of the length of the longer between s1 and s2
    int length1 = strlen(s1);
    int length2 = strlen(s2);
    int maxlength;
    (length1 > length2) ? (maxlength = length1) : (maxlength = length2);
    return maxlength;
}
```

Comment: `char addNumericStrings(char *s1, char *s2) {` but you return a `char *`.

Comment: Furthermore, `sum` is supposed to be a *string*, but you forget to *null-terminate* it.

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes, first please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the character `'0'` then *say* so. That will also make the code independent of ASCII encoding (which isn't the only encoding). Also, your `findMaxLength` is using the conditional expression in a way that many would consider "wrong" (including myself). I suggest something like `maxlength = length1 > length2 ? length1 : length2;` Or skip `maxlength` completely and just `return length1 > length2 ? length1 : length2;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. I did have a line that added a null terminator, but it didnt change the outcome, and didnt seem to matter for it being recognized as a string elsewhere in the script. I assume because it had one when I initialized. The line was ` sum[maxlength + 1] = '\0';` (replaced as a commented line in the original post)... but even re-adding it doesn't change the output.

Comment: Trust me, that null-terminator is important. Without it all functions that will look for the end (including your `printf` calls) will go out of bounds looking for it and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That is seems to work without you adding it is pure luck (some would argue that you're *unlucky* it works).

Comment: @J.Doe. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm new to c and I'm not sure what you mean. `char *s1` and `char *s2` are pointers. I create a new `*sum` pointer reference (I think) using `char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 2) );`. This was my best guess based on the link in shown in the OP. How should the line be different?

Comment: The return type of this function is `char`, but you return data of type `char *`. That's the problem.

Comment: You want to return a `char*` so the return type of `addNumericStrings()` must be `char*`, not `char`: `char* addNumericStrings(char *s1, char *s2)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Good to know. I'll remember that. I'm not sure if I added it correctly (to the right index) but, even with the added line, the return still fails. Am I missing something additional?

Comment: @J.Doe. That was it. Thanks! Add this as an answer and I'll mark it accepted!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: 'please don't use magic numbers.'. Also noted. But in this case, it was due to my inability to figure out how convert the summed up variable `total` back from an `int` into a `char`. I could never find a way to do it - so instead I filled the indexed location in the `char sum` with its ascii value. I.e. `sum[i +1] = 48+total;` How should I replace this line to convert the `int total` for insertion into the `char sum`?

Comment: Also, if I may ask - why the down vote?

Comment: You use `addend1[i] - '0'`, why can't you use `sum[i +1] = '0'+total`? It's really the same thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Fair enough. I had actually tried that, but it didn't work. However, I did it gain and now it's working. I must have fatfingered it somewhere the first time. Thx.

Comment: @Makyen **For archival reference, this question was not the result of a typo**. It was the result of contradictory information received from other stack answers about the right way to declare a pointer return. The "typo" comment was about an aside, unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a `char *` from your function, you have to use the appropriate return type:

```
char* foo(void)
//  ^
{
    char *bar;

    // ...

    return bar;
}
```